# Redshift Unload SELECT statement with \\

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

If I have the following statement within an AWS Redshift unload statement with the following syntax:

```
SELECT \\'{{"id":"\\' || id || \\'",\\' || url || ltrim(home, \\'{{\\')
from users_details
```

What do the \ imply?

The full statement within the python script is:

```
UNLOAD ('
        SELECT \\'{{"id":"\\' || id || \\'",\\' || url || ltrim(home, \\'{{\\')
        FROM users_details
    ')
TO {AWS Bucket}
    ALLOWOVERWRITE
    DELIMITER AS '\\t';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the author was trying to escape quotes within the query.

It is using `\'` to indicate a quote-within-a-quote, and the first `\` is preventing Python from trying to interpret the second `\`.

However, there is a better method shown in [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

> If your query contains quotes (for example to enclose literal values), put the literal between two sets of single quotation marks—you must also enclose the query between single quotation marks:
>
> ```
> ('select * from venue where venuestate=''NV''')
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But the column that this is pulling data from is from the home right?

Comment: The row will include values from `id`, `url` and `home`.